# Cannot update document's property in SharePoint 2013 using OpenCMIS

Tags: sharepoint-2013, opencmis

I'm using SharePoint 2013 and I'm trying to update a document's property with OpenCMIS 0.14.0

The code is simple:

```
final String PROP = "MyCustomProperty";
Session session = buildSessionWithAtomPubBinding("https://domain/_vti_bin/cmis/rest/?getRepositories");

OperationContext oc = session.createOperationContext();
oc.setFilterString(PROP);
CmisObject doc = session.getObjectByPath("/docs/contracts/doc.xsl", oc);
System.out.println("Doc id before checkout: " + doc.getId());

final Map<String, String> prop = new HashMap<String, String>();
prop.put(PROP, "IronMan");
System.out.println(prop);
CmisObject newObj = doc.updateProperties(prop);
```

But I get the following exception:

```
Doc id before checkout: 6010-512
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.exceptions.CmisConnectionException: Redirects are not supported (HTTP status code 302): Found
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.AbstractAtomPubService.convertStatusCode(AbstractAtomPubService.java:469)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.AbstractAtomPubService.put(AbstractAtomPubService.java:685)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.AbstractAtomPubService.put(AbstractAtomPubService.java:672)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.ObjectServiceImpl.updateProperties(ObjectServiceImpl.java:340)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.AbstractCmisObject.updateProperties(AbstractCmisObject.java:376)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.AbstractCmisObject.updateProperties(AbstractCmisObject.java:340)
    at it.alessandro.CMISTest.main(CMISTest.java:30)
```

Below there are the properties used to create the session:

```
org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.user=xxxxxxxx
org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.password=xxxxxxxx
org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.binding.atompub.url=https://domain/_vti_bin/cmis/rest/?getRepositories
org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.binding.auth.http.oauth.bearer=false
org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.binding.auth.soap.usernametoken=true
org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.binding.spi.type=atompub
org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.binding.auth.http.basic=false
org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.binding.auth.classname=org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.NTLMAuthenticationProvider
org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.workaround.omitChangeTokens=true
```

Is it a SharePoint's bug or there's something wrong in my implementation?

Comment: Do other CMIS operations work, such as search?

Comment: Sure, they work. I'm able to put a document, delete it, search content and so on. I'm also able to rename a custom property of a folder, but I get that error when updating a document property.

Comment: Can you try with the Apache Chemistry CMIS Workbench? That'll let you check if it's your code, or SharePoint. http://chemistry.apache.org/java/developing/tools/dev-tools-workbench.html

Comment: It's not possible to update a document's property in SharePoint 2013 using Apache Chemistry, please see this reference: http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/chemistry-dev/201403.mbox/%3CDA132DC248996047B6E9C009C7EE23D101008721BF@SE-EX022.groupinfra.com%3E. For that reason I define a specific OperationContext object to get only the property that I want to update.

Comment: Use the session parameter OMIT_CHANGE_TOKENS. See https://chemistry.apache.org/java/0.14.0/maven/apidocs/org/apache/chemistry/opencmis/commons/SessionParameter.html -> Workarounds.

Comment: I updated my question to add the full list of properties used to create the session. Even after adding "org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.workaround.omitChangeTokens" I get the same exception.

Comment: Do not use NTLM! You will run into all kinds of issues. This may or may not be related.

Comment: @FlorianMüller sorry for the late reply, but if I try to authenticate with provider CmisBindingFactory.STANDARD_AUTHENTICATION_PROVIDER I always get a CmisUnauthorizedException, while with CmisBindingFactory.NTLM_AUTHENTICATION_PROVIDER the authentication is successful.

Comment: The NTLM authentication provider is not reliable and should never used in production. It's only there for experiments. 
Check if your SharePoint server accepts basic auth. If not, enable it and the standard authentication provider should work.

Comment: Finally, I've been able to use Basic Auth and I got the same error.